# WPF - Rotate Transform Transition

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, transformation, transition

I am relativly new to WPF and I have a question concerning transitions in WPF:

How do I create and use them? My google search result are mostly about *animations* not *transitions*.

My goal is to create something like this:

Imagine I have a shape:

```
<Rectangle Width="100" Height="200" Name="shape_01" x:Key="shape_01" Fill="Green"/>
```

whoms rotation will be set during run-time to (yet) unknown values. Meaning, that I cannot use a `Storyboard` or `Animation` to create a transition.
I use the following code to set the rotation angle:

```
double angle = ....;

((shape_01.RenderTransform as TransformGroup)
    .Children.First(_ => _ is RotateTransform) as RotateTransform)
    .Angle = angle;
```

How can I transition the previous value to the currently set value?

Comment: WPF uses animations for "transitions".

Comment: @Clemens: I am sorry, but could you elaborate it a bit further, Sir?
I am not (yet) very familiar of the WPF-animation/transition/storyboard concept...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use a `DoubleAnimation` to "transition" a property from one value to another. If you do not set the animation's `From` property, the transition starts from the current property value.

```
double angle = ....;

var animation = new DoubleAnimation
{
    To = angle,
    Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
};

var transform = ((TransformGroup)shape_01.RenderTransform)
    .Children.OfType<RotateTransform>().First();

transform.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, animation);
```

Comment: How would you do that in XAML?